# Leetcode digit root

Tags: java

I am working on a leetcode:
Given a non-negative integer num, repeatedly add all its digits until the result has only one digit.

For example:

Given num = 38, the process is like: 3 + 8 = 11, 1 + 1 = 2. Since 2 has only one digit, return it.

MY code is as following, but it returns 1 when input is 20. I cant not figure out why staring at it for 20 mins, anybody can help?

Thanks a lot!

```
public class Solution {
    public int addDigits(int num) {
        if(num%10 == num){ //20%10 = 0//2%10 == 2
            return num;
        }
        int sum = 0;
        while(num%10 != num){
            sum += (num%10); //sum = 0
            num /= num; //num =2
        }
        return addDigits(sum + num%10);// 0+2

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you single-step through the code in a debugger?  If not, that is the place to start.  If you did, tell us what you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num /= num;` will always equal 1. ( that is unless num=0 and you don't want to divide by zero - thanks John Bollinger)
`sum += (num%10);` where `num=20` implies `20 =20%10 = 0`.
adding those two results up you get `0+1 = 1`.  1 is a single digit number and that gets returned.

perhaps you meant:

```
while(num%10 != num){
        sum += (num%10); //sum = 0
        num /= 10;  //I CHANGED THIS LINE ONLY
    }
```

Comment: Aw, I was hoping the OP would try debugging and find the error on his own :-)

Comment: Note: `num%10` is expensive and you can check if a number is a single digit with `num < 10` +1

Comment: `num /= num` will not *always* equal 1.  If `num` is `0` then the result is not defined, and the computation will cause an `ArithmeticException` to be thrown.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  i stand corrected :-) i'll edit my answer haha

Comment: Got it! Thanks guys!